# Linearly dependent columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that A, B $\in$ $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ are nonzero matrices such that $AB$ $= [0]$.
Show that the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent.

What I tried: I tried to arrange AB as a summation but couldn't find a way to break up the summation into columns and create an expression with constants set equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

$A,B$ are matrices which represent linear maps $f,g$ of $R^n$ in the standard base. $AB=0$ i.e $f\circ g=0$, since $B$ not zero, the image of $g$ is not zero so the kernel of $f$ is not zero. So the rank of $A<n$. This implies that the columns of $A$ which are $n$-vectors contained in the image of $f$ which has a dimension $<n$ are dependent.